# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer - working with param from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Trying to convert a param included in the the URL into an integer, to operate with it within a Controller - The format of the URL is like http://localhost:3000/charges?**data**=**149**&email=email@gmail.com

The charges_controller.rb looks like:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery with: :null_session

  def new
  end


  def create

    @amount = {}
    @amount = params [:**data**][:email].map(&:to_i)
    @amount.save

    customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      :email => params[:stripeEmail],
      :source  => params[:stripeToken]
    )

    charge = Stripe::Charge.create(
      :customer    => customer.id,
      :amount      =>  @amount,
      :description => 'Rails Stripe customer',
      :currency    => 'eur'
    )

  rescue Stripe::CardError => e
    flash[:error] = e.message
    redirect_to new_charge_path
  end

end
```

And the params I can see in better_errors screen detect already the 'data' amount:

```
{"stripeToken"=>"asdfasdf", "stripeTokenType"=>"card", "stripeEmail"=>"email@gmail.com", "data"=>"149", "email"=>"email@gmail.com", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"charges"}
```

In the live shell in better errors if I do params[:data].to_i it returns 149, but if I include it directly in the controller like:

```
@amount = {}
@amount = params [:data].to_i[:email]
@amount.save
```

it returns undefined method `to_i' for [:data]:Array

Tried also mapping them like:   `@amount = params [:data][:email].map(&:to_i)`,same result "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"

Comment: Why are you adding space in `params [:data]`? Have you tried `params[:data]`? I am not sure if Ruby would recognize such syntax correctly. I am also not sure what `**"data"=>"149"**` could mean. Please review your question.

Comment: The ** was for bold font - just removed it.  Tried with/without space, same results as detailed above.

Comment: Correction - you are right. Just did a tweak and it works now, so thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove space while calling :data on your params hash from `params [:data]` to `params[:data]`.